# Tkinter Button with icon: `_tkinter.TclError: image doesn't exist`

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

In a script, that I am writing I need a button with a little trash bin as an icon on it. I use the code shown below:

```
# Python 3.7.1
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="bin.png")

icon_button = tk.Button(master, image=photo)
icon_button.pack()
```

The following error occurs:
`_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1. doesn't exist`

Since I specified `bin.png` as the image file, I cannot really understand how `pyimage1` is specified in the error.

After some debugging, I realized, that the `PhotoImage` returns the string `pyimage1`, and therefore gives `"pyimage1"` as a parameter to the `Button`, but I still don't know how to fix my issue.

Comment: I am incredibly sorry if this is a duplicate and the same question as already been answered, but after watching through about 5 articles about this topic I still could not help myself.

Comment: _"After some debugging, I realized, that the PhotoImage returns the string pyimage1"_ is incorrect. It doesn't return a string, it returns an instance of `PhotoImage`. Also, I can't duplicate your problem. I don't think it's possible for _this exact code_ to give the error you say it does.

Comment: I checked it and it does not returna string, but apparently when printing out the PhotoImage in the __repr__ method of the PhotoImage class returns a string value, that seem to happen as well when used as parameter for the tkinter button.

Comment: _"when printing out the PhotoImage in the repr method of the PhotoImage class returns a string value, that seem to happen as well when used as parameter for the tkinter button."_ yes, the repr returns a string (by definition that's what repr does). When you assign the image to a button, it does not assign the repr. It assigns the actual object.

Comment: Why does it then say that the file "pyimage1" does not exist?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it's possible for _this exact code_ to give you a "pyimage1 does not exist" error. Either the file exists and is of proper format, or the code will crash before you have a chance to use the image to create the button.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The problem is that Relative path won't be accepted, i.e.</s> if you have your `bin.png` in `C:\` then you should do as-

```py
tk.PhotoImage(file='C:\\bin.png')
```

Now, if you still want to use relative paths then the following will do-

```py
import tkinter as tk
import os

Win = tk.Tk()
Img = tk.PhotoImage(file=os.path.abspath('bin.png')

tk.Button(Win, image=Img).pack()
Win.mainloop()
```

Or use this-

```py
import sys, os

def get_path(file):
    if not hasattr(sys, ''):
        file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file) 
        return file
    else:
        file = os.path.join(sys.prefix, file)
        return file
```

It simply just gets the full path of a file.

Now, use the function-

```py
...file=get_path('bin.png'))
```

Comment: I tried to use the absolute path, but it still did not work. Same error messageis thrown.

Comment: @byTreneib Try with the above on an actual terminal, because it's working fine on my end.

Comment: Could the issue be caused, because I am creating the image and the button as attribute of a different class than the master? I did not show it in the code since I dis not think it would be relevant.

Comment: @byTreneib No that's not it,  wait I'll post a function which should work.

Comment: Ok, I will try this out as soon as I can. Thank you for now!

Comment: @byTreneib Tell me if it did worked or not as if not, there might be something else in your code. Because the bare bone code is working fine.

Comment: _"The problem is that Relative path won't be accepted"_ is a false statement. Tkinter works fine with relative paths.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that. But also, the relative path won't work if the workspace is set to a different directory other than where the script exists, isn't?

Comment: That is not correct. Relative paths always work, but you have to use a _correct_ relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is trying to tell you that the object image does not exist, which means that you need another object to help you put the image in your button.

Using `Tkinter.PhotoImage` will provide an image object compatible with tkinter and custom_tkinter classes.

here is an example of making an image to a button:

```
image_PI = PhotoImage(file='your/image/path.png')
contact_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(
    ...
    ...
    ...
    image=image_PI,
    )
contact_button.pack(pady=(50, 10), padx=(20, 10))
```

Hope this helped.